# Number of characters in a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

```
       var a="password";
```

In any variable how to check if the length is not less than 6 characters   and not  > 12

```
     $(a).len();?????
```

Comment: Why limit password length to 12 characters?

Comment: If you ever wondered, [http://shouldilearnjavascript.com/](http://shouldilearnjavascript.com/) ? ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No need for jQuery.

```
if ((a.length < 6) || (a.length > 12)) { error .... }
```

[MDC reference on `string.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length)

[MDC reference on the String object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (a.length < 6 || a.length > 12) {
    alert('Invalid password. It must be between 6 and 12 characters long');
}
```